# Python 2.7 Opencv error, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Working on python 2.7(not anaconda). Operating system Windows server 2012 R2

The pypi installation mentions two fixes for this, installing Visual C++ redistributable 2015 and Universal C Runtime.
As well as a manual fix for older anaconda versions, which is for python3(I am not using anaconda version, and also my python version is 2.7 so presuming it doesn't apply in my case)
link here:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

installed both the dependencies but couldn't get it to work.
Any ideas on how I may fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 2.7 is still supported, this could be the possible solution.

**Installing OpenCV from prebuilt binaries:**

Below Python packages are to be downloaded and installed to their default locations.

1. [Python-2.7.x](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.msi)
2. [Numpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1/numpy-1.7.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download)
3. [Matplotlib](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/matplotlib-1.3.0.win32-py2.7.exe)

Install all packages into their default locations. **Python will be installed to C:/Python27/.**

After installation, open Python IDLE. Enter import numpy and make sure Numpy is working fine.

Download latest OpenCV release and install it : [Latest OpenCV-build](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/opencv-4.1.0-vc14_vc15.exe/download)

Goto opencv/build/python/2.7 folder.

Copy cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packeges.

Open Python IDLE and type following codes in Python terminal.

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```